# Leaflet in React.js - "dragend" event exception: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I get this exception when this event occurs, that is, when the user finishes dragging the marker. This is my React component:

```
import {useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';
import styles from './styles.module.scss';
import { MapContext } from './../../../../context/MapProvider';

const ZonesBar2 = () => {
    const [definingZone, setDefiningZone] = useState(false);
    const [markerInput, setMarkerInput] = useState({lat: '', lng: ''});
    // const [] = useState();
    const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);
    const {contextData, setContextData} = useContext(MapContext);
    const {mapRef, clickLocation} = contextData;

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(clickLocation.lat) {
            // Add markert to map
            let newMarker = L.marker([clickLocation.lat, clickLocation.lng], {draggable: true})
                .on('dragend', console.log('Marker dragged'))
                .addTo(mapRef);

            // Add to list of markers
            setMarkers((m)=>([...m, newMarker]));

            console.log(newMarker.getLatLng());
        }
    }, [clickLocation])

    return (
        <div className={styles.zonesbar}>
            <button onClick={()=>{setDefiningZone((p)=>(!p))}}>Nueva Zona</button>
            <div className={`${styles.newMarkerPanel} ${definingZone && styles.visible}`}>
                
                <label>
                    <span>Nombre:</span>
                    <input type="text" />
                </label>
                <label>
                    <span>Latitud:</span>
                    <input type="text" id='lat' />
                </label>
                <label>
                    <span>Longitud:</span>
                    <input type="text" />
                </label>
                <button>+ Marcador</button>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ZonesBar2;
```

I honestly can't figure out what's going on... I do need your expert's hands help please.
This is a screenshot of the error:
[image: leaflet error on dragend event for marker]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of stuff going on there, but what I see is this:

```js
let newMarker = L.marker([clickLocation.lat, clickLocation.lng], {draggable: true})
  .on('dragend', console.log('Marker dragged')) // <-- bad times right here
  .addTo(mapRef);
```

When you write `console.log('something')`, that expression is immediately evaluated. And console.log returns `undefined`...so leaflet is trying to fire a function which is `undefined`.  You need this:

```js
let newMarker = L.marker([clickLocation.lat, clickLocation.lng], {draggable: true})
  .on('dragend', () => { console.log('Marker dragged') }) // <-- callback
  .addTo(mapRef);
```

Now you're passing a proper callback, which is a function, not the return value of `console.log()`.

Comment: Thank you Seth. I've posted a new leaflet related question if you'd like to take a look... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67797591/leaftlet-updating-polygon-dynamically-in-react-js-application

Answer (score 0):

You must pass a function reference:

```
 let newMarker = L.marker([clickLocation.lat, clickLocation.lng], {draggable: true})
                .on('dragend', console.log('Marker dragged'))
                .addTo(mapRef);
```

Also dispose of the handler at the end:

```
return ()=> { newMarker.off('dragend'); }
```