# Leaftlet: Updating Polygon dynamically in react.js application

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

### EDIT: I've discovered that dragging the markers which are connected to the state (their references are saved), actually mutates it, that's why react is not detecting a change... now the question is how to reconcile these, the dragging with not mutation state.

I'm having issues updating a polygon dynamically after a marker is finished dragging (hopefully I can do it while the marker is being dragged!). I tried the marker events, using remove() for the polygon reference then creating a new reference and adding it again on marker's dragend, but this only duplicated the polygon and updates it a step behind.

Here's a video so you can see what's happening: https://youtu.be/aS-b09w6la0

I've tried all I could think of and every event that is on the leaflet docs.
This is my react component. I've changed it so much and tried so many events and states that it's getting too unclean already...

```
import {useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';
import styles from './styles.module.scss';
import { MapContext } from './../../../../context/MapProvider';

const ZonesBar2 = () => {
    const [definingZone, setDefiningZone] = useState(false);
    const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([]);
    const [polygonRef, setPolygonRef] = useState([]);
    const {contextData} = useContext(MapContext);
    const {mapRef, clickLocation} = contextData;

    function onNewZoneClick() {
        setDefiningZone((p)=>(!p));
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (!definingZone) {
            console.log('zone saved.');
        }
    }, [definingZone]);

    // Add a new zone --- 
    useEffect(()=>{
        if(clickLocation.lat && definingZone) {
            //Create polygon reference
            var newPolygonRef = L.polygon([], {color: 'red'}).addTo(mapRef);
            setPolygonRef(newPolygonRef);

            // Add marker to map
            var newMarker = L.marker([clickLocation.lat, clickLocation.lng], {draggable: true})
                .on('dragstart', ()=> { polygonRef.remove(); setPolygonRef(L.polygon([], {color: 'red'}))})
                .on('dragend', ()=> { polygonRef.addTo(mapRef); })
                .addTo(mapRef);

            // Add references to markers list
            setMarkers((m)=>([...m, newMarker]));

            // Remove event listeners
            return ()=> { newMarker.off('dragend'); }
        }
    }, [clickLocation]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        if (markers?.length) {
            const latlngs = markers.map(m => { return [m.getLatLng().lat, m.getLatLng().lng] }); 
            polygonRef.setLatLngs(latlngs);
        }
    }, [markers]);

    return (
        <div className={styles.zonesbar}>
            <button onClick={onNewZoneClick}>{!definingZone ? 'Nueva Zona' : 'Guardar'}</button>
            <div className={`${styles.newMarkerPanel} ${!definingZone && styles.invisible}`}>
                
                <label className={styles.name}>
                    <span>Nombre:</span>
                    <input type="text" />
                </label>

                <div className={styles.markersPanel}>
                    {
                        markers.map((m, i) => (
                            <div>
                                <fieldset>
                                    <legend>Marcador #{i+1}</legend>
                                    <label>
                                        <span>Latitud:</span>
                                        <input type="text" value={m.getLatLng().lat} />
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                        <span>Longitud:</span>
                                        <input type="text" value={m.getLatLng().lng} />
                                    </label>
                                </fieldset>
                            </div>
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ZonesBar2;
```

I know my approach is not correct, any help is appreciated.

[image: leaflet polygons]

Comment: This is a relatively involved thing you're trying to do, I don't think we can attempt debugging this with a static code block, I think we need a live code sample to take a decent shot at this.  Also, I think it was mentioned in another question, but what you're trying to create has been well established with leaflet-geoman and leaflet-editable, so I would really considering using those as opposed to trying to reinvent the wheel.  If you want to bulldoze through and use your own code, plz post a codesandbox reproducing the bug and we'll be able to really help.

Comment: Thank you Seth. You are very right, not reinventing the wheel is the way to go and the right decision a good software architect would make. My goal is to learn, I do want to learn how to create a wheel, I find so much joy doing it, and I hope someday I'm able to contribute to libraries such as the Fantastic Leaflet. I'm so amazed at the knowledge people have to do such things. Would you mind guiding me, giving me some references on how to reach this level? And by the way, I've been reading and coding non-stop today, and I've achieved it! https://youtu.be/TDa-L8N-B4o Posting answer soon.

Comment: Nice!  That's what its all about. Whatever event you have attached to `dragend`, you may consider attaching to `drag` as well, so that the polygon moves as you drag. Demo looks great.

Comment: This issue with using drag is that this is inside a hook... and updating context... ouch. The mutable ref "globalLines" does the trick of being a middleman between the leaflet reference and the React context... 
useEffect(()=>{ 
...  
  .on('dragend', ()=> {
     lett finalPos = [newMarker.getLatLng().lat, newMarker.getLatLng().lng];
     let newLines = globalLines.current.map(x => {
     if (x[0] === initialPos[0] && x[1] === initialPos[1]) {
 return finalPos;
 } else return x;
   });
      setContextData(prev=>({...prev, lines: newLines}));
})
...}}, [clickLocation]);

Comment: How can I learn more about how Leaflet works? What would be the roadmap for me to be able to contribute to Leaflet for example? What are some good reads? Thank you Seth.

Comment: The way to learn about leaflet, or anything, is just to build stuff.  Learning will occur naturally as long as you keep creating things, pushing the limits of what you think is possible, read the docs, and read the source code.